# Find creation date for a Postman test-case

Tags: postman, postman-testcase

Is it possible to find when a Postman test request was created? Does the Postman keep history of changes for a test-case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a Changelog in the app that will show you the details of the changes within a Collection. For free users, this will just show you a line item and a date.

[image]

For pro and enterprise users, this shows the actual diff of the changes:

[image: Changelog]

More information can be found here:

https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/workspaces/activity_feed_and_restoring_collections/